# Сменить цвет (RGB) белой картинки через CSS

Tags: html, css

Есть белая картинка https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5hxV.png
Есть цвет в RGB, например (255, 30, 50)
Как через CSS фильтры сделать картинку именно такого цвета?

Comment: Эм.. Ничего не понял.

Comment: А.. Всё-таки понял...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поддержка браузерами не впечетляет, но ничего лучше не придумал:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, silver, blue);
}

div {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/M9Ipk.png) rgb(255, 30, 50);
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.colored {
  background-blend-mode: color-burn;
  -webkit-mask: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/M9Ipk.png);
  mask: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/M9Ipk.png);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="colored"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не прямой ответ, это всего то вариант....

`filter-ом` максимум ближе к желаемому можешь так обвести `rgb(255, 30, 50)` данным цветом. Жаль у `filter inset` отсутствует, можно было бы закрасить внутрь....

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgb(255, 30, 50));
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5hxV.png" />
```